# {%static %} the page displays the line itself {%load static %} instead of loading the desired file

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I wanted to connect a css file to this html file, I wanted to add it via `{% load static %}`

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>Brewtopia Cafe form</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style_contact.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<header>
```

this is urls.py in the app

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Brewtopia_view, name='brewtopia'),
    path('Contact/', views.Contact_view, name='contact')
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

these are views.py in the app

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def Brewtopia_view(request):
    return render(request, 'Brewtopia.html')


def Contact_view(request):
    return render(request, 'Contact.html')
```

settings.py settings in static

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

the css file is located in the folder C:\Projects\brew\brewtopia\users\static\users\css

I added static and wanted to upload a css file, but the error is in the screenshot
[image]

but even if you delete {% load static %} it won't work

Answer (score 0):

In views.py, you need to import the template renderer:

```
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

And then, in each of your view functions, you return something like:

```
def view_name(request) -> HttpResponse:
    template = loader.get_template('module_name/Brewtopia.html')
    context = {} # variables you use in your template go here- read the reference at the end for more info

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Don't forget to substitute "module_name" for the name of the app.

This is a pretty decent example using templates:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial03

And this has some more in-depth info:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/

Comment: The problem is that I can't connect the css file to Contact html via struct

Comment: Render doesn't process the django template language-- hence why the stuff in {{...}} and {%...%} doesn't get processed. To render your view using the django template language, you use django.template.loader to load a template, and django.template.render to render it, which from what you posted, is not what you're doing now.

Comment: I inserted your piece of code and changed all the addresses correctly, the html page is loaded, but the css is not connected to this page. Load static string is entered on the screen with the page

Comment: Whoops, I missed something- the path in the html file should be 'users/css/style_contact.css'. Though I think my original answer was still needed as well?